# passing alphanumeric value in querystring in url does not work in flash

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, flash, actionscript

I am having a flash application where I want to send paramters to it via the javascript from a defaul.aspx page.

I have a paramter called Id where it can accept alphanumerica values.

the query string in the url works fine if I enter just numbers for the Id, and takes me to the specific page relted to that id , but if I enter a combination of numbers and characters like 001A , it does not work.

this is the code I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getQueryVariable(variable) 
    {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);  
        var vars = query.split("&");  
        for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) 
        {    
            var pair = vars[i].split("="); 
            if (pair[0] == variable)
                return (pair[1]);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

and then later I assigned the first page of flash application to it.

```
flashvars.StartPage = getQueryVariable("Id");
```

and then passed the flashvars into  swfobject.embedSWF

I also don't want to change anything in my mxml files in flash side

I appreciate if anyone could help me what the problem is

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to use JavaScript to process the value from querystring and then to send to flash.

Just make use of `ExternalInterface.call` function to grab variables (In this case : GET ) from URL.

Here's the code how it works. Add this code inside your MXML.

```
var pageURL : String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
var paramPairs : Array = pageURL.split("?")[1].split("&");
                for each (var pair : String in paramPairs)
                {
                    var pairHolderx:Array = pair.split("=");
                    arrVals[counter]=pairHolderx[1];
                    counter++;
                }
```

So if your URL is like http://www.stackoverflow.com/page.aspx?id=230A78&id2=8934
The `arrVals[0]` contains 230A78 and `arrVals[1]` contains 8934

Comment: Thanks for the help,as I earlier said I do not want to change the MXML file, I want to do it from javascript from either html or defaul.aspx file